# ng-content (tooltip) is not populating the content

Tags: css, angular

Trying to display tooltip via `ng-content`. But it is not working. If the `ng-content` is outside to `div` which holds the `for` loop, then it is working and displaying the tooltip by appending to the `div` - but the problem is tooltip should be at end of the sentence.

**aligned-label** component template

```
<div class="aligned-label">
    <div *ngFor="let label of getLabels()" [innerHtml]="label">
        <span ng-bind="label">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**check-box** component template

```
<div class="control__content">
    <aligned-label class="control__label" [labels]="labelText">
        <ng-template #popTemplate>
            <span [innerHtml]="tooltipText"></span>
        </ng-template>
        <span *ngIf="tooltipText" class="mdi mdi-information" [tooltip]="popTemplate" container="body"></span>
    </aligned-label>
</div>
```

`labeltext`, `tooltipText` are input to checkbox component

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is replacing the HTML of you span and thats why you don't have the `ng-content` anymore. Are you sure you want to have that `innerHTML` there?

Comment: tooltip text is html template if I don't use it then is displaying the template as plain text

Comment: yes but its replacing the content of the span, so the ng-content won't exist anymore once is populated with the value of the label